# How to revert a specific property to its saved value (EF4)?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework

Well, I'm using MVC3 and EF4 and everything is great... Except when i have to update an object but not all of its properties.

Here's how its implemented so far:
I have a class, it's properties, and a DbSet for it on my DbContext. My page is sending back a JSon with all values of that object (including the ones I want to update and the ones i want to be left unchanged). On the controller, i'm receiving the object and just changing it's State to EntityState.Modified and calling the SaveChanges() of the DbContext.

As I said, everything works great, but i do want that some of the values received by that JSon to be discarded, leaving their values untouched as they are on the database.

How can I achieve that?

Thanks in advance for any help...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure of your code but when you only want to update certain properties on an update call to EF  you should do it like so....

```
db.Person.Attach(person);
db.Entry(person).Property(x => x.Name).IsModified = true;
db.SaveChanges();
```

so you will modify whichever properties you want and leave alone which ever ones you don't.

Answer (score 0):

You may also try this to..

```
using (DBContext newCtx = new DBContext())
{
     newCtx.Employee.Attach(emp);
     newCtx.ObjectStateManager.ChangeObjectState(emp, System.Data.EntityState.Modified);
     newCtx.SaveChanges();
}
```

Reference : [**Update Entity in Entity Framework**](http://entityframeworktutorial.net/update-entity-in-entity-framework.aspx)

Comment: But, in that case, you're not choosing which properties to leave untouched and which ones to update... Nope. That won't do it at all...